# What is RaasLeela?

Tags: krishna

I was reading this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/274/754), and I read the accepted [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/301/754) under this question.

The answerer used a word Raasleela , what actually is Raasleela?
I have seen episodes and Programes . I think word  Leela is creating some situation or a play.
But what that RassLeela is? Does it mean sex? If yes , then why will God want to do it, if its not then what is it actually? and doing RaasLeela with more than one?

Comment: Raas Leela means dance.

Comment: Raas is one type of garba or play we do in Gujarat in Navaratri festival.

Comment: why God wanted to do that? @ParthTrivedi

Comment: It's not sex, It's a dance form played by lord Krishna with gopikas. It is very much similar to Dandiya Raas played in Navratri festival in many states of India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry frnd it not a sex ...

Reason :

load krishna like to play rass .... may u agree 
and leela means its one kind of magic

at a time when load krishna play rass there is many gopi's and all want to play rass with shri krishna

so shri krishna do there leela

so that then can play rass with each and every gopi is we can said rassleela ...

and in rass two person are needed to play so its one krishna and another all gopi and krishna play with all of gopi its ...... Rassleela

Answer (score 2):

No. Raas Leela is not sex. Raas is one type of dance or act we play during Navratri festival. Boys and girls hold sticks called "Dandiya" in hands and play the dance. Raas Leela means play of dance with more than one.  Actually in Raas the partner is changed during the dance play. So we play it with everybody.

This Raas Leela give pleasure to all of them who are playing and all of them who are watching it also. GOD wanted to do Raas Leela to win hearts of Gopis who were friends of GOD. This gives fun loving moments to all.

Comment: why God wanted to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Raas is one type of dance or act we play during Navratri festival. Boys and girls hold sticks called "Dandiya" in hands and play the dance. Raas Leela means play of dance with more than one. Actually in Raas the partner is changed during the dance play. So we play it with everybody.

This Raas Leela give pleasure to all of them who are playing and all of them who are watching it also. GOD wanted to do Raas Leela to win hearts of Gopis who were friends of GOD. This gives fun loving moments to all.