# Why Shiva created the universe for Kshetrajñahah?

Tags: shiva, brahman, creation, agamas, shaiva-siddhanta

We find

> It has been ascertained that the earth and other objects are the created ones (they are basically products) and ascertained that the creator of all these products is Isvara. **Since that Isvara is  a Supreme Being associated with perpetual contentment (nitya trupta)**, the created objects could be of no use to Him. Nor the created worlds could utilize themselves, since they are non-intelligent. **Since Lord Siva is with such a greatness and  lordship, he cannot perform purposeless actions; He cannot create purposeless objects.** Therefore, through the process of elimination, it is ascertained that the creative function and the created worlds are neither for their own sake nor for the **ever-content** Lord who has created all these, **but only for an intelligent being existing apart from the created and the Creator**. That intelligent being is known as the *kshetrajñahah*. Mregendra āgama 6.2.

[Abhinavgupta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhinavagupta) provides following explanation about *kshetrajñahah*.

> The field (*kshetra*) is the body of worldly beings where the seed of action is nurtured. In the case of worldly beings the embodied self (jivātma) is called the **knower of the field (kshetrajñahah)** , who remains polluted by temporary impurities. However, in the case of enlightened ones, the embodied self is called *kshetra*.

Therefore it is clearly explained, Lord Shiva has not created the universe for his own, he created for Kshetrajñahah. But why would Shiva create the universe for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chapter of that *Mrigendra Aagama* is talking about '**Pashu Lakshanam**' or the 'Nature of the Bound Soul', so the Kshetrajna there refers to Individual souls.

*Why would Shiva create the universe for them ?*

In the Shaiva Siddhantam there is purpose for the creation of universe. However in the Vedanta, creation by Brahman is just considered purposeless and [solely Leela.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/what-exactly-is-a-leela-%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%b2%e0%a4%be-is-there-a-scriptural-definition-of-leela-%e0%a4%b2%e0%a5%80%e0%a4%b2%e0%a4%be/16188#16188)

This is given by the reasoning of this in the Aagama:

> Nor the created worlds could utilize themselves, since they are non-intelligent. **Since Lord Siva is with such a greatness and lordship, he cannot perform purposeless actions; He cannot create purposeless objects.**

So, the reason given is that *Lord Shiva won't create purposeless objects like unintelligent matter just for play.* There must be some reason. And the reason is individual soul by nature is composed of **Anava impurity** and when that impurity is removed then only soul attains Supreme Shivam state. So, Shiva has purpose to create Universe and it's because he wants that souls get rid of Anava and attain Supreme state:

> For the creation of the world as inclusive of body(tanu), instrument(karana), sources of enjoyments 
>   (bhoga) and so forth, soul is the necessitating factor. Even while expounding the nature of Siva, the
>   specific nature of the soul has been told. **The soul, in its embodied state, is with a knowledge shrouded 
>   by the darkness of anava-mala. It is not independent.** Such characteristics were expressed there. Now, 
>   the essential nature of the soul is succinctly established.
>   (Mrigendra Aagama 6.1)

Comment: Soul created after creation? Or individual soul existed before creation?  Before such reason presuming soul existed prior to the Creation.  Creation if for sake of removing anava mala of individual soul, then how anava mala came in the very first place. I think something is missing here. Or translation is missing something. Or reason has some esoteric meaning which we're unable to understand so far.

Comment: @Rohit Singh Rathore Soul is existing from beginning but soul has Anava mala from beginning by default...

Comment: @Tezz It's interesting that Shaiva Siddhanta has reason for creation instead of saying just leela. Shiava Siddhanta is dualistic right? But does Shiva Siddhanta say how Anava Mala came at very first place?

Comment: @The Destroyer Anava exists by default, it is seen through direct evidence... for eg. If you hadn't Anava mala you would be able to perform fivefold task which Shiva does.. but we can't do it because of Anava mala.. of course we have other malas like Karma, Maya etc.. also... but in the beginning state also we can't perform because Anava mala was there by default... and it can only be removed by Grace of Shiva/Shakti...

Comment: @TheDestroyer KS doesn't just say 'leela' it has explanations like Shaiv Siddhanta as well. I will provide in future.