# What is the message that Lord Krishna giving to us stealing butter?

Tags: krishna, symbolism, leela

We all know that Krishna is god, but he also stolen butter in his childhood, so what someone can perceive good in that?

How can we look into it in a positive way?

Comment: Related or duplicate of [Why did Krishna steal butter and milk?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/274/3500)

Comment: This is a valid question. Asking the reason why a God did something and the symbolism behind an act is a valid question to ask. Analysis of questions is also fine. It doesn't bring up opinions.There are several similar questions.

Comment: "Primarily opinion based"? Seriously? How can anyone think of closing such a beautiful question? No wonder this site isn't graduating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, Krishna can't be called a thief because he is Lord of the worlds and everything is His.

> [BG 5.29](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=5&field_nsutra_value=29&etsiva=1&etgb=1) One attains Peace by knowing Me who, as the great Lord of
>   all the worlds, am the enjoyer of sacrifices and austerities, (and)
>   who am the friend of all creatures.

Why did Krishna perform such mischievous activities?

Duryodhana offered Krishna very opulent items, but Krishna didn't accept but instead went to Vidura's home to accept bananas.

He stole butter from their houses as he is controlled by gopis love and by doing such activities, gopis love towards Krishna increased further. Gopis would like if Krishna comes and steals the butter.

They loved Krishna far greater than their own children.

> [SB 10.14.49](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/14/49): King Pariksit said: O brahmana, how could the
>   cowherd women have developed for Krsna, someone else’s son, such
>   unprecedented pure love — love they never felt even for their own
>   children? Please explain this

.

They would externally appear to complain to Yasoda but actually they enjoy those activities and in the pretext of complaining, they describe and remember what activities Krishna did and relish them.

> SB 10.8.24: Within the house of Nanda Maharaja, the cowherd ladies
>   would enjoy seeing the pastimes of the babies Rama and Krsna. The
>   babies would catch the ends of the calves’ tails, and the calves would
>   drag Them here and there. When the ladies saw these pastimes, they
>   certainly stopped their household activities and laughed and enjoyed
>   the incidents.
>
> SB 10.8.28: Observing the very attractive childish restlessness of
>   Krsna, all the gopis in the neighborhood, to hear about Krsna’s
>   activities again and again, would approach mother Yasoda and speak to
>   her as follows.
>
> SB 10.11.9: To pure devotees throughout the world who could understand
>   His activities, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Krsna, exhibited
>   how much He can be subdued by His devotees, His servants. In this way
>   He increased the pleasure of the Vrajavasis by His childhood
>   activities.

There is nothing mundane in these lilas. 
We should not see these types of lilas from perspective of mundane morality and imitate them.

> BG [4.9](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=4&field_nsutra_value=9&etsiva=1&etgb=1) He who thus knows truly the divine birth and actions of
>   Mine does not get rirth after casting off the body. He attains Me, O
>   Arjuna

.